# Windows 7 like login screen

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

How/What is the most similar login screen to windows 7 one/how can one customize it to get it look like Windows 7?
I have version 18.04.

Comment: What research have you done so that people don't recommend what you've already tried?

Comment: Not much, but I saw some guides pointing to making te desktop looking like Windows 7

Comment: And you'll need to mention which version and desktop environment of Ubuntu you're on. Answers may need that information.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly windows 7 but there is a [Chicago95](https://github.com/grassmunk/Chicago95) theme that is rather faithful to windows 95 for xfce. It also has some light dm stuff at the end that helps customize the login screen.